# Typecasting in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, jscript

How to convert the following `Java` code to `JScript`:

```
return ((IPOSBasket) basket).getOriginalCashierID();
```

When executing the above code in `Java`, it works fine. But if I try to execute as a `JScript`, I am getting `NULL` value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/2454376

Comment: Are you talking about [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) or [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone really talks about JScript..

Comment: If it is jScript, are you using it to compile .net assemblies? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET That jScript is typed. Ecma javascript and jscript in IE are not typed so there is no need for conversion (unless you need string to number).

Comment: In case you try to run this script in a browser then `return basket.getOriginalCashierID();` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by HMR in comment, the following line works fine:

```
return basket.getOriginalCashierID();
```

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of getting downvotes XD

> [Java and Javascript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java/245068#245068)
>
> Greg Hewgill 2008

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to cast anything, how are you getting the basket variable?

Also, as a good practice don't do any operations in a return statement, it sometimes hides errors/problems in code and harms readability.

So if it is JScript:

```
var basket : IPOSBasket = IPOSBasket(x); // this is made up, don't know what you are doing here.
var originalCashierID = basket.getOriginalCashierID();
return originalCashierID;
```